# Flutter switch inner border shadow

Tags: flutter, shadow

I used flutter_switch package for switch button. All of customize is nearly identical, that I wanted. But I want to add inner border shadow for switch button border. How to add inner border shadow or customizing? And I found alternative way that use flutter neumorphic package. But this package can't add 'ON', 'OFF' label or do I miss something? Please answer possible way, to build like in picture.
[image]

Comment: did you find anything??

Comment: I can't find exactly like that. Instead of, I used FlutterSwitch with custom decoration.